# Search Box mouseenter and mouseover events dosen't work with scrollTop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, search-box

I created a search box on top of the page,
when the page gets scrolled down the search box opacity is changed to 0.75
when the page gets scrolled back up the search box opacity is changed back to 1
the bug - I wish that when the search box gets hovered or clicked (on desktop) or gets taped (on mobile) to turn back the opacity to 1, but it doesn't work

Here is my demo page - http://demo.codefuel.com/thegreatest/testpage.html?hiddenMode=true

Here is the part of the events code   -

```
var intervall = setInterval(function(){

   if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 && $(window).scrollTop() < 505) {
            $('#bg_wrapper,#searchbox').animate({ 'opacity': 0.75 }, 500);
    }
   else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500) {
            $('#bg_wrapper,#searchbox').animate({ 'top': -100, 'opacity': 0.75 }, 500);
    }  
   else if ($('#bg_wrapper').mouseover()) {
            $('#bg_wrapper,#searchbox').animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 500);
    }                    
    else  {
            $('#bg_wrapper,#searchbox').animate({ 'top': 0, 'opacity': 1 }, 300);
    }
},500);
```

Comment: Firstly, don't use an irrelevant interval but set logic inside `window scroll` event and debounce it and stop/dequeue any pending animation

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy one, the logic is broken.

You set up a condition where either the first if or the second else if will be used and then the other two will be skipped over all the time.

Here's the corrected version:

```
    var intervall = setInterval(function(){
       if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 && $(window).scrollTop() < 505) {
                $('#bg_wrapper,#searchbox').animate({ 'opacity': 0.75 }, 500);
       }
       else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500) {
                $('#bg_wrapper,#searchbox').animate({ 'top': -100, 'opacity': 0.75 }, 500);

                if ($('#bg_wrapper').mouseover()) {
                        $('#bg_wrapper,#searchbox').animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 500);
                }  
        }           
        else  {
                $('#bg_wrapper,#searchbox').animate({ 'top': 0, 'opacity': 1 }, 300);
        }
    },500);
```